# Can I safely put a function in php foreach statement declaration?

Tags: php

Is it safe to put a function in the foreach statement ?

```
foreach( get_class_methods( $object ) as $entityMethod ) {
    // Do something
}
```

Does the get_class_methods() function will be called at each loop ?
Is there any drawback ?

Comment: Simple answer: Yes it is safe, no there is no drawback. Longer answer: the only thing that won't work is iteration by reference, everything else will behave exactly as it would if you assigned the return value to a variable and iterated that instead. There are some nuances under the bonnet that make this not 100% true, but to all intents and purposes it is in the real world.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only time this would be unsafe is if the function could return something that was not iterable (like `null`, or a `string`, etc).  That particular function does return `null` on any error.

Answer (score 0):

The function will only get evaluated once, when entering the loop. But you could have tested that yourself by making a function that increments a global variable every time it's called.

As far as drawbacks, none that I can think of..